# Questions regarding on matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I know this will be sounds so hilarious but i just want to know.

Usually we defined `2x2` matrices, it will be in the form of,

```
A[1][1], A[1][2], A[2][1],A[2][2]
```

Are we able to write a matrix that has difference of each element in the matrices as 0.5? How can I write the simple code in c++? Since i am dealing with jacobian.

```
A[1][1] A[1][3/2] A[1][2]
A[3/2][1] A[3/2][3/2] A[3/2][2]
A[2][1] A[2][3/2] A[2][2]
```

Comment: You need a remapping from your weird half-space to natural numbers.  It's really just about the relabeling.

Comment: What do you mean by that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As possible solution, you should define your own C++ class with preferable step of array indexes and overload the [] operator.

[Updated] Here it's raw example of such class:

```
class MyArray{

private :

    int* pA;
    unsigned int n;
    float m_step;

public:

    MyArray(unsigned int n, float step ): pA( new int[n] ), n(n), m_step(step){}
    ~MyArray(){ delete [] pA, n =  0 ;}

    void populate(int p) {
        for (unsigned int  i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            pA[i] = p;
            p++;
        }

    }

    int& operator[](float i){ /** Calculate correct internal array index based on input i and specified m_step. Return array element value by calculated index */ }
    const int& operator[](float i)const{ /** Calculate correct internal array index based on input i and specified m_step. Return array element value by calculated index */ }

    unsigned int size(){ return n;}
    unsigned int size()const { return n;}

};
```

Comment: Can you explain more? I still do not get it. Sorry.

Comment: Check here for more details: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/62240/ Here it's good code examples too.

Comment: The matrices involved in the code are most likely just like normal matrices values[i]={1,2,3}. But i can't see one of them involved float/double number. Huu..

Comment: @MazayaJamil, have update the answer with code example of such class.

Comment: Using `float` as an index is a _very_ bad idea, unless you implement some sort of rounding.  You don't want `i/m_step`, converted to an integral type, since this will occasionally result in one less than the index you want.

Comment: @JamesKanze, good catch. Actually, that was just raw example of how this can be implemented, because I can bet that author of the question is not familiar even with C++ classes syntax very well :) And exact implementation of such object is very depends how it will be used. It will be needed to put a lot additional checks to make it use safe.

Comment: @N1ghtLight It's not clear what he knows in general, but my feeling is a bit like yours.  There's no problem with using `float` as an index if it's just a demo as to how to write such a class, but unless you're sure that the reader understands the implications, you really should warn that it's just for demo purposes, and much more work is needed if you expect it to actually work.

Comment: Dear @N1ghtLight. Yes. I am not so familiar with c++, that is why I ask of there's some possible solution to do so since I am dealing with float numbers. :) but it explain quite well for a super beginner like me. Thanks.

Comment: @MazayaJamil, thanks to James for explanation :) I have updated my example and left only commented out text description in overloaded operators.

Comment: Well thanks to both of you. At least I know something better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.  At the lowest level, an index is the
offset relative to the start of the array, which corresponds to
a physical address in memory, and physical addresses are always
cardinal numbers.

A more general answer would be that you can use any type which
can be ordered, or which supports equality and a compatible
hashing as an index, just use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`
instead of `std::vector`.  So roughly:

```
std::map<double, std::map<double>> A;
```

The problem in your case is what type you use for the key.
Because of issues involving rounding, `double` is *not*
advisable as a key.  `std::ratio` might be adaptable; otherwise,
you'll have to figure out something yourself.  If you're pretty
sure that the values will all be either very close to an
integer, or very close to something ending in `.5`, and that the
values will be reasonably small, you can probably get away with
a special ordering:

```
struct Order
{
    bool operator()( double lhs, double rhs ) const
    {
        static double const epsilon = 0.25;
        double l;
        modf( 2 * lhs + epsilon, &l );
        double r;
        modf( 2 * rhs + expsilon, &r );
        return l < r;
    }
};
```

(This supposes that all of the indices are non-negative.)  At this point, however, you might as well create your own
matrix, using `l` and `r`, above, as physical indices.

Be aware, too, that in C++, `3/2` is `1`, and not `1.5`.